# Python 3.5: slice vs islice vs alternatives? Efficiency comparison

Tags: python, list, slice

## Context

This is a general question regarding efficiency.
I have a list and I need a consecutive run / sublist from a list. Typically, this is done via a slice:

```
my_list[start:end]
```

however, slice generates a copy of the original list (at least references of the original list). Thus it is possible that this operation is slower than if it did not do this.

`islice` is an alternative which makes an iterator instead. Since I only care about having all the values at one, not iterating over them, I will have to type cast:

```
list(islice(my_list, start, end))
```

## Background Work

To do some comparisons I randomly sliced/isliced 10 times on lists of increasing size from 1 to 10,000:

```
is_vals = []
s_vals = []
for l in range(1, 10000):

    my_list = [random.random() for k in range(l)]

    for p in range(10):
        i = random.randint(0, l)
        j = random.randint(0, l)

        if i < j:

            start_time = time.clock()
            list(islice(my_list, i, j))
            is_vals.append(time.clock() - start_time)
            start_time = time.clock()
            my_list[i:j]
            s_vals.append(time.clock() - start_time)

        else:
            start_time = time.clock()
            list(islice(my_list, j, i))
            is_vals.append(time.clock() - start_time)
            start_time = time.clock()
            my_list[j:i]
            s_vals.append(time.clock() - start_time)

print(statistics.mean(is_vals) - statistics.mean(s_vals))
```

what I found is that slice is still faster, with the difference between islice and slice being 2.99e-05.

I am not sure, but I will go ahead and chalk that up to typecasting the iterator object.

## Question

is there a more efficient way than slice to get a consecutive run / sublist in a list?

Bonus: is there a way to more or less typecast a list / tuple into a slice? e.g. turn [i,j] into i:j?

Comment: So both methods produce a new list object. Why even look at `islice()` **at all**, since it can only introduce more complexity? `list()` calls `iter()` on the the iterator (which in this case returns `self`). `islice()` has to call `iter()` on the list (returning an list iterator object). All round, much more work.

Comment: Turning a start and stop value into a slice you can do with `slice(i, j)`. This is already answered elsewhere, see [How can I use colon (:) in variable](//stackoverflow.com/q/40531795) or [Python slice how-to, I know the Python slice but how can I use built-in slice object for it?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3911483)

Comment: @MartijnPieters hence the question, I am looking for an alternative and perhaps a new list without references to the original could have been faster...

Comment: No, there is no faster method for creating another list with a contiguous selection of elements from a source list.

Comment: Note that there isn't really such a thing as a *type cast* in Python. Objects have a fixed type, if you need an object with a different type, you need to create a *new* object. Many types offer ways to create a new object of that type by converting something, which is what `list()` does to an iterator. Or `int()` with a string, etc.

Comment: Did you think that `list(islice(...))` was going to somehow *avoid* making a copy? There's no way it could do that. Also, `islice` can't jump straight to the `start` value it needs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't beat `mylist[start:stop]` in speed, no. Not if you want a *new list object* containing the same elements from a contiguous area of the input list.

That's because the `list` type implementation has direct access to the internal storage for a list object. You can't get access to those elements any faster from outside.

Only use iterators when *memory efficiency* is important. Iterators add a iteration speed overhead, they generally are *not* faster. In this case, the expression `list(islice(my_list, start, stop))` will do the following work:

1. Create a list iterator object for `my_list`; this will yield elements from `my_list` as you iterate over it.
2. create a new `islice()` iterator object; this will skip `start` elements from the list iterator, then produce values until you reach the `stop` index.
3. produce an iterator from the `islice()` iterator object. In this case that will just re-use the same object, but this is still a separate (C) function call.
4. produce a new list object from all elements that the iterator object produced in step 3 yields.

The `mylist[start:stop]` call on the other hand only does this:

1. Call `mylist.__getitem__(slice(start, stop))`. This method directly produces a new list object with the same elements copied form its internal array directly to the new list object array.

Comment: just a nitpick: It doesn't need to be contiguous, even with a `step` normal slicing notation should be fastest.

Comment: @MSeifert: yes, if there is a step it is not contiguous; I just focused on the case in the question. I'll do some editing later on.

Comment: `islice` should be faster if I gave you a large enough slice to handle. On average, memory allocation and copying elements to it is slower than creating a single iterator object.

Comment: @spidey: the op is *creating a new list* from the output of `islice`. The speed trial is between `listobj[start:stop]` and `list(islice(listobj, start, stop))`, not just creating the iterator object.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
import time
from itertools import islice
import statistics

l = 1000000
is_vals, s_vals = [], []
my_list = [random.random() for _ in range(l)]
for p in range(10):
    i = random.randint(0, l//3)
    j = random.randint(l-l//3, l)

    start_time = time.clock()
    sum1 = 0
    for k in islice(my_list, i, j):
        sum1 += k
    is_vals.append(time.clock() - start_time)
    start_time = time.clock()
    sum2 = 0
    for k in my_list[i:j]:
        sum2 += k
    s_vals.append(time.clock() - start_time)
    assert sum1 == sum2

print(is_vals)
print(s_vals)
print(statistics.mean(is_vals)-statistics.mean(s_vals))
```

This shows islice is slightly faster than slice. This is because Python interpreter creates a new list (my_list[i:j]) and then iterates over it in the line

```
for k in my_list[i:j]:
```

whereas in the line

```
for k in islice(my_list, i, j):
```

it does not create a new list and directly iterates over my_list from ith to jth indices. However, when you write

```
list(islice(my_list, i, j))
```

the new list is also created, thus you don't see any advantages over slice.